# How to specify in itunes connect that we want to launch application after it is approved?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

I think there is an option somewhere. We can decide whether to launch app once it's approved or to determine the launch date my self.

I forget that option.

I look around, after uploading the app where I can change the option.

I found none

I rejected the app I upload and try uploading again hoping to see that option. That option simply doesn't show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's an option once you choose ready to upload.

Comment: I rejected my upload and try to upload another one. That option doesn't show up.

Comment: Definitely comes up for me. Second screen once you choose ready to upload.

Comment: No. I was asked whether I change feature. I said I don't. Then that's it, I am ready to upload.